# Is it possible to not close error tooltip?

Tags: flycheck

An error tooltip is automatically closed after like 5 seconds. Could you prevent this? So it would be closed only when you move cursor? I changed tooltip-hide-delay but it did't help.

Comment: Flycheck does not use popups for error display.  What package do you use to get these tooltips?

Comment: Thanks, I though it's flycheck build-in functionality. It turned out flycheck-pos-tip and it has flycheck-pos-tip-timeout variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out I use flycheck-pos-tip for tooltips and it has flycheck-pos-tip-timeout variable.